# flutter: objects fields becoming null on creation in Isar inspector

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-isar

I really liked Hive and recently i decided to try Isar as a local DB for my App ,However i'm facing a problem when trying to create an object into a collection using the Isar inspector as the fields are becoming null after creating the object .

**User Class**

```
import 'package:isar/isar.dart';
part 'user_model.g.dart';
@collection
class User {
  Id id = Isar.autoIncrement; // you can also use id = null to auto increment
  String? name;
  int? age;
}
```

Here is the class that i'm generating the collection from

**Creating an object from Isar inspector**

and here is a GIF to better discribe the problem
[fields are null on creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5uVT.gif)

any help or info is appreciated thank you

Comment: Welcome to the forums. Please do not post images of code, post the (relevant) code within the question, as well as any output as text.

Comment: @JaredFarrish thanks for the clarification,  i updated the post .however there is no output in this particular  case so i had to include a gif to better describe my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put the text between double quotes on the inspector so instead of `simple text` be like that `"simple text"`

Comment: oh man Thanks a lot, i have a habit of using single quotation marks when declaring Strings and when i tried that it didn't work so i didn't really think of that lol , i think the reason behind this behavior is that Isar uses rust and not dart under the hood  which doesn't support single quotation marks for strings